# Show that a curve is regular

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Consider the curve given by

$\alpha(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      (t,0,e^{-1/t^2}) & t > 0 \\
      (t,e^{-1/t^2},0) & t <0 \\
      (0,0,0) & t = 0
\end{array} 
\right. $

Problem: Prove that $\alpha$ is regular for all $t$.

Since a curve is regular at $t_0$ iff $\alpha'(t_0) \neq 0$ the curve seems to violate this at $t=0$. Perhaps this has something to do with the curve not being continuously differentiable at that point, but I have a feeling I'm missing something big here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\alpha$ is regular for $t \neq 0$ since the first component of $\alpha'(t)$ is $1\neq 0$. But this actually holds for $t=0$ too (use the definition of derivative in case you don't see it immediately).

Comment: regular doesn't mean analytic ?

Comment: So it just comes down to the fact that a limit in both directions is the same.